# Convert Array to String in React Native

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, string, react-native

I need help with my college project.
I am downloading data from the database in the form of an Array, how can I download only the text content and e.g. display it in the console?

**PHP file on server**

```
<?php
include('db.php');

$Username = $decodedData['Username'];

    $sql=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT text FROM scanned WHERE username = '$Username'");

    /*every time it fetches the row, adds it to array...*/
    while($r[]=mysqli_fetch_array($sql));

echo json_encode($r);

?>
```

**A function that sends data to the server and receives the result as Array**

```
function getItem(username){
    var InsertAPIURL = "http://192.168.0.87/AM_LOGIN/getScanned.php";

    let text;

    var headers = {
      Accept: "application/json",
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    };

    var Data = {
      Username: username,
    };

    fetch(InsertAPIURL, {
      method: "POST",
      headers: headers,
      body: JSON.stringify(Data), //convert data to JSON
    })
      .then((response) => response.json()) //check response type of API (CHECK OUTPUT OF DATA IS IN JSON)
      .then((response) => {
        text = response
        console.log(JSON.stringify(text))
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        alert("[BŁĄD]" + error);
      });
  }
```

**Result**

[image: Result from console]

Thanks for help

Comment: Can you clarify where is the issue? What do you expect as an output on the console?

Comment: I just want a clear text, eg. "Witaj w wikipedii!".

Comment: I know i have to map and iterate this array but i dont know how.

Comment: For that text you can simply do `text[0].text`

Comment: Thanks, now i can make for loop and iterate over all items in array.

Comment: Yes, i made it alteady, I'll post full code later. Thanks you for help